# Pch not plotting circles, only plotting lines

Tags: r, plot, graph, scatter-plot, alpha

I'm trying to make a graph with different zones on the x axis and average cases on the y axis. When I try to plot this I get solid bars for each point even though I've used the function `pch =` and `type = p`. Here is my code

```
plot(region1_data$Zone, region1_data$total_cases, 
     type = "p",
     pch = 21,
     bg = "#035DAB",
     cex=2, 
     srt=45, 
     ylim = c(0,550),
     ylab = "",
     xlab = "",
     yaxt = "n",
     xaxt ="n")
mtext(side = 1, text = "Zone", line = 5)
Axis(side = 1, 
     at = region1_data$Zone, 
     labels = region1_data$Zone, 
     tick = TRUE, las = 2,  
     srt = 60, 
     adj= 1)
```

What I would like are 4 points with a line running through them that have the same colour which changes transparency as they increase on the y value. I've tried making a new vector doing something like this...

```
pch = region1_data$Zone
pch = as.numeric(pch)
```

But that doesn't work either. Can anyone tell me how to do this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My x axis values were factors. I changed them using `as.numeric()`.